# React Chart.js onClick for custom legends

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm using react-chartjs-2 to create a Line chart for my application.

For this app, I did a legend customisation and I could generate them using this:

```
// Chart component
<Line ref={ (chart) => chart ? this.insertLegends(chart) : null }
      data={this.state.chart} 
      options={this.state.options}  
/>

// Method which insert the html content
insertLegends(chart) {
   this.refs.chartLegendContainerGlobal.innerHTML = chart.chart_instance.generateLegend();
}
```

First, is this a right approach? 
I had to create an inline condition inside the component to prevent chart to be null.

Second, how and where can I put an onClick event for each legend?

I'm very lost on this, is there a better way to do this legend customisation??

Answer (score 1):

If you give the ref a callback, then you won't get a value of null. Doing an inline ref like this causes the first render to be null and then the second render will have the element.

So you should change your refs to:

```
applyRef(ref) {
    this.legend = ref;
}

render() {
    return (
        // Chart component
        <Line ref={this.applyRef}
              data={this.state.chart}
              options={this.state.options}
        />
    )
}
```

For adding a click event handler, if you can't add an `onClick` attrib for some reason, then you can set it in your `insertLegends` method:

```
handleClick(e) {
    // Do something here...
}

insertLegends(chart) {
    this.refs.chartLegendContainerGlobal.innerHTML = chart.chart_instance.generateLegend();
    this.refs.chartLegendContainerGlobal.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have a question, how can I call my method insertLegends? With this approach, my this is undefined inside applyRef.

Comment: I figure out how to solve combining your idea using the ref. I'm going to post it. Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: @ItaloBorges You need to bind `applyRef` in your constructor. `this.applyRef = this.applyRef.bind(this);`

Answer (score 0):

After some trouble and research, I figure out how to add the legend and control the click inside of it.

```
// Inside my render method I added a simple ref to my component
<Line ref='chart' data={this.convertData(this.props.data)}  options={this.state.options} />

// Inside this method I'm able to get all the references that 
// I need to inject the html inside a container for the legends and 
// also to assign a click for each legend label
componentDidMount() {
   let legends = this.refs.chart.chart_instance.generateLegend();
   this.refs.chartLegendContainer.innerHTML = legends;

   $(this.refs.chartLegendContainer).find('.legend-item').on('click', (e) => {
      let index = $(e.currentTarget).index();
      this.refs.chart.chart_instance.data.datasets[index].hidden = !this.refs.chart.chart_instance.data.datasets[index].hidden;
      $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('disable-legend');
      this.refs.chart.chart_instance.update();
   });
}
```

**UPDATED**

After the commect of @Chase DeAnda, I changed a little bit based on his considerations:

```
// Applying the callback function to the ref
<Line ref={this.applyRef} data={this.convertData(this.props.data)}  options={this.state.options} />

// Inside the method I call the method to insert the legends
applyRef(ref) {
   this.legend = ref;
   this.insertLegends();
}

// Generates the legend and added them to my container element
// Also give them the onClick event
insertLegends() {
   let legends = this.legend.chart_instance.generateLegend();
   this.refs.chartLegendContainer.innerHTML = legends;
   $(this.refs.chartLegendContainer).find('.legend-item').on('click', (e) => this.onClickLegend(e));
}

// During onClick I update the chart
onClickLegend(e) {
   let index = $(e.currentTarget).index();
   this.legend.chart_instance.data.datasets[index].hidden = !this.legend.chart_instance.data.datasets[index].hidden;
   $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('disable-legend');
   this.legend.chart_instance.update();
}
```

Comment: Couple points: String refs are going to be deprecated soon, so you should be using the ref callback to set the refs. You should create a class method for handling the click event and pass that into the event listener instead of doing it all inline in the componentDidMount method.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda, I just updated my code with your considerations. Better approach! Thanks!